# PHP textarea content download not working properly

Tags: php

below is the php code I am using,

```
         <?php
         if(isset($_POST['tarea'])){
                 $filename = $_SESSION['Zone'].'.zone';
                 $data = $_POST['tarea'];
                 header("Cache-Control: public");
                 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
                 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
                 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                 echo $data;
                 }
        ?>
```

I am just trying to download content of text area as downloadable file but it is outputting html code too in the file, I have tried to use die($data); instead of echo $data; but it does not work.
Please help me to solve this problem out. Thanks.

Comment: put `exit;` after `echo $data;`

Comment: I tried it but its not working

Comment: then you might have content some where else in your code

Comment: Actually I am populating **textarea** named **tarea** with data fetched from database and then allowing user to download it if he wants to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can resolve your problem by using

```
$data = strip_tags($_POST['tarea']);
```

instead of

```
$data = $_POST['tarea'];
```

If this will not help you then use

```
ob_end_clean();
```

before using header() function.

Comment: I am simply echoing the output of `$data` before using headers, it is giving me content only from tarea but, I don't know somehow headers are throwing html code too in the downloadable file so `strip_tags($_POST['tarea']);` is not working either

Comment: I just want headers to put $data in the downloadable file not my whole html code.

Comment: means in that downloaded file you are getting html code of your file?

Comment: yes absolutely, I am trying to download the file and it is giving me all the HTML of my file.

Comment: Yes it works except </body></html> is still coming in the output file, can you help me out with it?

Comment: Thanks overall problem is solved just forgot to put `exit;` at end

Answer (score 0):

I created two files, tarea.php (for the form) and download.php

tarea.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['Zone'] = 'test';

?>
<form action="download.php" method="post">
<textarea name="tarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit">     
</form>
```

download.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['tarea'])){
    $filename = $_SESSION['Zone'].'.zone';
    $data = $_POST['tarea'];
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    echo $data;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I am actually using this code in download.php where session is already started. The problem that is arising is when I try to download the file it outputs html alongwith textarea code, I have tried to put die(); at the end but it is taking no effect.

Comment: Actually my tarea.php file looks like this


`<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['Zone'] = 'test';
require './include/download.php';
?>
<form action="download.php" method="post">
<textarea name="tarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit">     
</form>`

So I am not getting any problems from session, it is giving perfect name to my downloaded file real problem is even after trying `die($data);` `die();` and `exit;` it still outputs html content alongwith textarea content in my file.

Comment: I can't seem to recreate your error. I tried your code to require the download.php but removed it from the `<form action="" method="post">` and it's working fine.

Comment: Yeah I think the same way as you are, after simply echoing the output of $data before using headers, it is giving me content only from tarea but, I don't know somehow headers are throwing html code too in the downloadable file so strip_tags($_POST['tarea']); is not working either – Anfal 1 min ago edit 
I just want headers to put $data in the downloadable file not my whole html code.

Comment: And 1 more thing I am not allowing user to input something then download it, I am populating the tarea with data from database then allowing user to download it, P.S tarea is readonly.

Comment: `<form id="ContactForm" method="post" action="./download.php">
<div  class="textarea_box">
<div class="bg">        <textarea style="resize:none" rows="10" cols="50" readonly="readonly" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" name="tarea"><?php require './include/download1_SERVER.php'; ?>
</textarea></div>        
</div>
<a href="#" id="download" class="button1"onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">Download</a>
</div></form>`

Comment: Thanks for the help, `ob_end_clean();` in the beginning and `exit;` at the end solved the problem.